# Kinematics plots of raw GPS data from .txt file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, gps, coordinates

I have a set of raw GPS data in .txt file and I need to generate easting and northing coordinates of the data and plot it as kinematic curves. How can I read raw GPS data from .txt in MATLAB and plot the kinematics plots of its easting and northing coordinates.
My data is in following format with approx 9000 rows.

Time: 0 (secs) Latitude: 43.73361796 (degrees) Longitude: 15.899775390 (degrees)

---

Time: 3 (secs) Latitude: 43.73352768 (degrees) Longitude: 15.899741860 (degrees)

---

Time: 5 (secs) Latitude: 43.73355115 (degrees) Longitude: 15.899622800 (degrees)

---

I am happy to post the little of progress I have made if you needed to see. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/community/11073-capturing-and-mapping-gps-example?q=GPS)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read the data into MATLAB.

```
fid = fopen('filename.data', 'rb');
data = textscan(fid, 'Time: %d (secs) Latitude: %f (degrees) Longitude: %f (degrees)');
fclose(fid);

[times, latitudes, longitudes] = data{:};
```

If you have the Mapping Toolbox you could use an UTM [map axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/axesm.html):

```
axesm utm
```

Then plot your coordinates

```
setm(gca, 'zone', utmzone(latitudes, longitudes))
plotm(latitudes, longitudes);
```

If you do not have the Mapping Toolbox, you could use this [file exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14804-wgs2utm--version-2-) to convert latitude/longitude to UTM.

Comment: Thanks, Suever.
What is the function of 'rb' from the first line? And would the 'filename.data' be say answer.txt( if that's the filename?

Comment: @Sujal It just specifies to open the file in binary mode for read-only access. You can actually omit that if you want.

Comment: thanks.
when i try to run the code this is an error message shown by matlab,

Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file
identifier.

I'm thinking aren't we already using fopen?

in meantime, I will fiddle a little bit and see how I go.

Comment: It likely means that it can't find the file that you specified